# Object label in GAE Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models

In my usual django code I use the **unicode** function to give each object a label...this appears in the admin interface as the oject label in the objects listed...

```
class apprd(models.Model):
   usr = models.ReferenceProperty(User)
   approved = models.BooleanProperty(default = True)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return ('approved one')
```

but now i have moved to GAE and this feature does not seem to be supported...
is there any work around or am I doin a mistake

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in GAE, because the GAE admin console does not read - indeed, has no access to - your model definitions. It only has access to the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/, you can get the full Django admin interface running inside GAE.